# Get parent and first span child jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this structure:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="number">1</span>
            <p class="list-title"><a href="#">Welcome</a></p>
            <img src="images/like.png" class="like" />

            <div class="subcomments">
                <div class="comments">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="number">2</span>
                        <img src="images/like.png" class="like" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I want when click on the class "like" appears the content of span.number, i.e.  goes to the father and gets the content of the span with class number.

I'm trying this:

```
$('.like').parent().children('span:first').text()
```

But always gives me 1 in the two situations, instead of giving 1 in the first like, and 2 in the second like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need jquery [**siblings()**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QaQHA/1/)**

```
$('.like').siblings('span:first').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) :

```
$('.like').siblings('span:first').text();
```

This in itself will always show 1 - because the selector `.like` is returning 2 elements - with the following code (`.siblings('span:first').text();`) running against the first element both times - you need to use each to loop each values :

```
$('.like').each(function() {
    alert($(this).siblings('span:first').text());
})​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/NDb6h/)

Comment: Show me 1 in the two situations.

Comment: @JamesCtreli its showing you one because your not using each to loop through the `.like` selections. See my update

Answer (score 0):

you should use `this`

```
$(.link).click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.number').text();
   //  $(this).parent().find('span:first').text(); // same thing
   //  $(this).closest('.number').text();          // same thing
})
```

when you just write   `$('.link').parent().find('span:first').text()`;
it always will take first `.link` class and take its span value, when you use `this` it uses exactly that `.link` that you have clicked on